# Literature request for effect of Aspect Ratio and Wing Sweep on critical angle of attack?

Tags: aircraft-design, stall, wing-sweep, aspect-ratio

So I'm trying to find academic literature detailing how both aspect ratio and taper ratio affect the critical angle attack of an aerofoil - namely for a v. low AR wing (AR<1), and high sweep (~75 degrees), i.e. where vortex lift dominates at high AoA.

The best I've found so far this the diagram below from Roskam detailing changes in Clmax with flaps for different planform dimensions, but no joy, including reviewing Raymer, and Nikolai's fundamental aircraft design books.

Anyone know any good literature outlining stall angle by varying these two parameters?

[image: Roskam diagram]

Comment: I'm pretty sure results like that have been published as a NACA or NASA technical report at some time, which I hope is academic enough for you, but I don't know one off the top of my head.